# How to setup the CLI interface and beast-shell - Maven project #ucrbeast #beast

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-14, beast

how do I execute the instructions below?

"CLI: To setup the CLI interface and beast-shell, extract the binary package in .tar.gz format. Run $BEAST/bin/beast to launch the command line interface."

then I need to run the command line to create a Maven project.

```
Dev: To create a new Java/Scala project for Beast using the following command.

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example.beastExample -DartifactId=beast-project \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=edu.ucr.cs.bdlab -DarchetypeArtifactId=beast-spark -DarchetypeVersion=0.9.5-RC2
```

I already ran the first line of the command in cmd but something is missing.
does the entire command only work if executing the first part of the statement first?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to launch beast-shell by entering "beast" , it is likely that you haven't added it to your PATH variable.

Once you have added beast's bin directory to PATH variable, you would be able launch beast-shell via terminal.

for example, assume that i have the beast project in my HOME dir, then I would run the following:-

```
~ % export PATH=$HOME/beast-0.9.5-RC2/bin:$PATH
~ % beast
```

Hope that helps!